# La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

Tengo un problema al intentar guardar datos de un formulario

me manda el siguiente error:

> La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.

mi código es el siguiente:

```
 NpgsqlCommand  cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("f_factura", conexion, transaccion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Transaction = transaccion;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", int.Parse(codigof.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_cliente", Convert.ToString(cliente.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_proveedor", Convert.ToString(proveedor.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_total", Convert.ToInt32(total.Text));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

estes es el SP

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_factura(f_cliente character varying,f_proveedor character varying,f_total integer)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
     f_codigo integer;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO facturacion(cliente,proveedor,total) VALUES (f_cliente,f_proveedor,f_total) RETURNING codigo into f_codigo ;
INSERT INTO dtfactura(codigo) VALUES (f_codigo);
RETURN f_codigo;
END
$BODY$;
```

y esta es la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE public.facturacion(codigo serial primary key,cliente character varying(100),
                proveedor character varying(100),total integer)
```

PD:me manda error en

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", int.Parse(codigof.Text));
```

Comment: por favor comparte un ejemplo de los datos que insertas y también un screenshot de los tipos de datos de la tabla, ademas de el store procedure que haces referencia.

Comment: @OrlandoAguilera ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: Verifica que valor trae codigof.Text

Comment: Si el problema se presenta en `int.Parse(codigof.Text)` validaste que el contenido del `codigof.Text` tenga un valor numerico valido ? Si esta vacio va a fallar la conversion

Comment: es que en (codigof.text) nesecito que me retorne el ultimo valor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que te lo regrese no lo mandes como parámetro,  lo debes de obtener del resultado de la consulta.

Borra esta linea

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", int.Parse(codigof.Text));
```

y al final pon

```
 codigof.Text = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar ())
```

en lugar de

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: gracias, me funciono

Answer (score 1):

Podrias validarlo usando

```
int codigof = 0;
if(!int.TryParse(codigof.Text, out codigof))){
   MessageBox.Show("Ingrese un codigo valido");
   return;
}

//resto codigo y usas
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", codigof);
```

el int.TryParse() intenta convertir pero te permite validarlo, si puede convertir te dejara el valor en la variable de salida

Comment: nesecito que en (codigo.text) me retorne el ultimo valor

Comment: pero el codigo que nos muestras no hace eso, falla porque debes proporcionarle tu a ese parametro el valor del codigo